# Can Enterprise Architect Python API be used to connect to running instances of EA

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

I currently use the following code to open a new instance and then query it,

```
eaRep = win32com.client.Dispatch('EA.Repository')
eaRep.OpenFile("Model.eapx")
```

However, I now require to access the EA file that has already been opened. Is there a way to do it with Python API for Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the running instance like this:

```
app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("EA.App")
```

Comment: Just a remark: connecting to the 64 bit EA version does not work. I found that out _the hard way_ :-/

Comment: @qwerty_so I guess that could be related to the fact that it's using win**32**com. Do you know if there is an alternative for 64 bit?

Comment: Well, I simply use the 32 bit EA version as long as it is available. I have to use Win11 on my Mac M1 which is pain enough.

Comment: Guys, I use Sparx EA 16 64-bit with pywin32 version 306 and it works.